# Approximations in physics

Tags: error-analysis, approximations

I have a very abstract at the same time awkward question. In many formulas across physics we need to take several approximations and often we derive formula from previous formula which had certain approximations in them. By error analysis we know that errors keep getting carried forward. Hypothetically can there be situation in future when almost every advanced formula we use, which is a result of derivation of several heavily derived formulas(I am referring *several heavily derived formulas* as those which are derived from highly approximated formula), be filled error quite significantly high and our calculations are thrown off by huge percentage of error and inaccuracy.

Can the error propagation in formula and theorems be a major problem we face in the future of physics?

(*Please note that I am not talking approximations involved in process of integration.*)

I am just curious to know to what level the approximations we take, effect the calculations we perform.I know this is a very awkwardly framed question. If you have any suggestions on improving the language of the question or any other changes, please let me know.

Comment: From certain premises you derive certain conclusions, maybe using approximations. If conclusions are not in agreement with observations you start again: maybe the approximation is bad, maybe the premises. However, I am sure this is already clear to you, but I see not much more than this.

Comment: Yes, I know, I am just being very imaginative here.

Comment: I do not think that is a likely scenario. If an argument leads to a chain of approximations so long that the uncertainties spiral out of control, then the predictions will be very bad, and the physicist involved would not be able to get credit for the approximation. He would have to find a new way to approximate. Or a theorist might discover why the approximation failed, and find some way to tame the divergence. Also, many real physics approximations today are divergent in the first place, yet they work.

Comment: Can you give at least one example of a formula derived from a previous formula that was itself known to be an approximation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every formula in physics turns out to be an approximation eventually. But experiments give physics rigor. We learn from those what the domain of applicability of an approximation is, and how good it is within that domain. This is the only possible solid foundation: nature gives us phenomena, not axioms.